# Capture substring and send it to a function that modifies it and can replace it in this string

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, replace, regex-group

```py
import re


def one_day_or_another_day_relative_to_a_date_func(input_text):
   #print(repr(input_text)) #print what you have captured, and you should replace
   return "aaaaaaaa"


def identify(input_text):
   some_text = r"(?:(?!\.\s*?\n)[^;])*"

   date_capture_pattern = r"([12]\d{3}-[01]\d-[0-3]\d)(\D*?)"

   previous_days = r"(\d+)\s*(?:dias|dia)\s*(?:antes|previos|previo|antes|atrás|atras)\s*"
   after_days = r"(\d+)\s*(?:dias|dia)\s*(?:después|despues|luego)\s*"

   n_patterns = [
   previous_days + r"(?:del|de\s*el|de|al|a)\s*" + some_text + date_capture_pattern + some_text + r"\s*(?:,\s*o|o)\s*" + previous_days,
   after_days + r"(?:del|de\s*el|de|al|a)\s*" + some_text + date_capture_pattern + some_text + r"\s*(?:,\s*o|o)\s*" + previous_days,
   previous_days + r"(?:del|de\s*el|de|al|a)\s*" + some_text + date_capture_pattern + some_text + r"\s*(?:,\s*o|o)\s*" + after_days,
   after_days + r"(?:del|de\s*el|de|al|a)\s*" + some_text + date_capture_pattern + some_text + r"\s*(?:,\s*o|o)\s*" + after_days]

   #Itero la lista de patrones de búsqueda para que el programa intente con uno por uno
   for n_pattern in n_patterns:
       #Este es mi intento de realizar el reemplazo, aunque tiene problemas con modificadores non-greedy
       input_text = re.sub(n_pattern, one_day_or_another_day_relative_to_a_date_func , input_text, re.IGNORECASE)



input_texts = ["8 dias antes o 9 dias antes del 2022-12-22",
           "2 dias despues o 1 dia antes del 2022-12-22, dia en donde ocurrio",
           "a tan solo 2 dias despues de 2022-12-22 o a caso eran 6 dias despues, mmm no recuerdo bien",
           ]


#Testing...
for input_text in input_texts:
   #print(input_text)
   print(one_day_or_another_day_relative_to_a_date_func(input_text))
```

Incorrect output that I am getting, because if I incorrectly capture the substrings, the replacements will also be incorrect

```
"aaaaaaaa"
"aaaaaaaa"
"aaaaaaaa"
```

Having well-defined limits, I don't understand why this capture pattern try to capture beyond them?

And the output that I need is that:

```
"aaaaaaaa"
"aaaaaaaa, dia en donde ocurrio"
"a tan solo aaaaaaaa, mmm no recuerdo bien"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several errors in your code, among which:

1. You are printing the result of the `one_day_or_another_day_relative_to_a_date_func` function. Print the result of `identify` instead.
2. In the `identify` function you are not returning the result text. Add `return input_text` at the end of it.
3. Make the "o..." suffix optional.
4. Use [regex alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) instead of multiple patterns, otherwise you may get unexpected results.

Fixed code (I've also made it more compact):

```py
import re


def one_day_or_another_day_relative_to_a_date_func(input_text):
   #print(repr(input_text)) #print what you have captured, and you should replace
   return "aaaaaaaa"


def identify(input_text):
   some_text = r"(?:(?!\.\s*?\n)[^;])*"
   date_capture_pattern = r"([12]\d{3}-[01]\d-[0-3]\d)(\D*?)"
   previous_days = r"antes|previos|previo|antes|atrás|atras"
   after_days = r"después|despues|luego"
   prev_or_after = r"(\d+)\s*(?:dias|dia)\s*(?:" + previous_days + "|" + after_days + ")\s*"
   preposition = r"(?:del|de\s*el|de|al|a)\s*"
   suffix = "(?:" + r"\s*(?:,\s*o|o)\s*" + some_text + prev_or_after + ")?"
   pattern = prev_or_after + some_text + preposition + date_capture_pattern + suffix
   input_text = re.sub(pattern, one_day_or_another_day_relative_to_a_date_func , input_text, re.IGNORECASE)
   return input_text


input_texts = ["8 dias antes o 9 dias antes del 2022-12-22",
           "2 dias despues o 1 dia antes del 2022-12-22, dia en donde ocurrio",
           "a tan solo 2 dias despues de 2022-12-22 o a caso eran 6 dias despues, mmm no recuerdo bien",
           ]


#Testing...
for input_text in input_texts:
   #print(input_text)
   print(identify(input_text))
```

Result:

```
aaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaa, dia en donde ocurrio
a tan solo aaaaaaaa, mmm no recuerdo bien
```